# Permission needed to create an environment from a GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have an automated setup to create a git repo, but this setup cannot create GitHub environments.

As part of the setup, though, an initial workflow runs, which is supposed to create those environments:

```yaml
- name: github repo setup
  env:
    GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
  run: |
          gh api -X PUT -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' -H 'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' /repos/$org/$repo/environments/tst
```

The `gh` command is tested and works from my terminal. Unfortunately, in the workflow, this fails with:

```
gh: Resource not accessible by integration (HTTP 403)

{"message":"Resource not accessible by > integration","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/deployments/environments#create-or-update-an-environment"}
```

Looking at the [linked docs](https://docs.github.com/rest/deployments/environments#create-or-update-an-environment), I need to add the permission `administration: write`. But this is a GitHub Apps permission, and I am inside a workflow.

I did try to add `permissions: write-all` to my workflow, but it did not help.

How can I have this step creating environment from a GitHub Actions workflow?

Comment: You need to create a token that _does_ have `write` access to `administration` (which is not one of the _"available scopes"_ that `{read,write}-all` would set) and provide that to your workflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like I either a manual step to create environments, or a manual step to create a token. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here:

1. Create a personal access token with the required permissions and add it to the secrets.
2. Create a GitHub OAuth App, give it the right permissions and use an action to retrieve its token as part of the workflow:

   ```yaml
   on:
     workflow_dispatch:
   jobs:
     demo_app_authentication:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
         - name: Generate a token
           id: generate_token
           uses: actions/create-github-app-token@v1
           with:
             app_id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
             private_key: ${{ secrets.APP_PRIVATE_KEY }}

         - name: Use the token
           env:
             GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ steps.generate_token.outputs.token }}
           run: |
             gh api octocat
   ```

See:

- [Making authenticated API requests with a GitHub App in a GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/making-authenticated-api-requests-with-a-github-app-in-a-github-actions-workflow)
- [Automatic Token Authentication - Granting Additional Permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#granting-additional-permissions)